# asp.net application with multiple projects cannot load type of page code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.Net application that uses multiple web projects.  It is set up to conform to the way Microsoft says to do this.  To be clear there is one solution with multiple web project where one serves as the base project and the others are children.

I have it all working pretty well.  Recently I took out a VB project and replaced it with a C# project.  Now in that project whenever I try to load a page under the base project it says that it cannot load the type like what is discussed here:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306155

When you just browse the web form from the project though (not run the solution for debugging) you do not get this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the solution build? Can you see where it fails when running in debug? go to 'Debug -> Exceptions...' and tick CLR Exceptions Thrown tick box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may have just broken a reference in the main project.  Whenever you remove a project that is referenced by project, it automatically removes it as a dependency wherever it's used.

Comment: That was it.  Ugh I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Wouldn't that break the compilation build? Or did you not try rebuilding?